# No-Listing policy with postfix (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, spam

I'm running an experiment on a virtual machine. In the virtual machine I've installed ubuntu and Postfix as a mail server. I followed the guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix , only the "configuration" part (the 11 points). 
Now I need to set-up 2 spam protections: grey-listing and no-listing.
For the grey-listing I used postgrey and it works.
My doubt is how to implement the no-listing. Basically I need to set up at least 2 Mx-records, one that works and one that doesn't. 
Can I do this with postfix?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nolisting is completely software independent, as it is enacted entirely in DNS records. Nolisting basically means you set an invalid Primary MX record, with your actual, functional mailserver on a lower priority MX record.

This could cause some issues with programs that do not follow the SMTP RFCs, and I honestly don't know how effective it is, as spammers used to always try the lower priority MX records, as those servers tended to be less maintained.

To answer your question, yes, you can do that with postfix, or qmail, or any other MTA that you feel comfortable administering, I just can't see it being particularly effective.

Comment: Thank you.The experiment involves the effectiveness of this technique, I will not really use it (the mailserver).
Where can I set the MX Record then? I'm working locally, the emails will come from another Virtual Machine

Comment: Well, the MX records come from your DNS server, it just depends on who administers that. If you admin it, you can quite easily set mutiple MX records.

Comment: Ok so after reading online I might try to use BIND9 DNS server to do this. I have a host-only network configured via Virtualbox. Now my question is, is it possible to install bind on the host machine and configure the guests so that they use this dns to resolve names?

Comment: Yes, of course it is, you could also use something lighter, like TinyDNS..